# JBoss not able to load Coldfusion

Tags: web-applications, configuration, coldfusion, jboss

I was using JBoss for four months for loading a CF project which is in the deploy > default folder as .war. Inside that there will be CFIDE, CFdocs, WEBINF and METAINF folders will be there. Now I am trying to migrate to a new machine. I copied the whole JBoss folder to new machine and added the required environmental variables. But I am getting this error. I saw one blog saying to set hosts in etc of windows. I tried that also. But no help. I am new to JBoss. Can you please point me in the correct direction ?

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:102)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    coldfusion.CfmServlet.init(CfmServlet.java:79)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:94)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA logs.

JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem as said below.

- I downloaded ColdFusion 10 Installer from Adobe.
- Installed CF as J2EE configuration. And in .war format.
- Then downloaded JBoss 5.1. And extracted to the required folder.
- Then extracted the Cfide folder and web-inf folder, which I got from extracting cfusion from ColdFusion installation folder, to the jBoss server>deploy>.war folder.
- Then created the jboss-web.xml in the web-inf folder and gave the content as follows

  ```
  <jboss-web>
      <context-root>project name</context-root>
  </jboss-web>
  ```
- Then accessed as localhost:port/project name.
  Works like a charm.

References :

- [Fusion Cube](http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/coldfusion-on-jboss-standalone-primer)
- [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18c28-7fbd.html)